# Can I Use B1/B2 to travel to the US When Applying F1

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas, f1-visas

I'm living in Vancouver and currently holding a valid B1/B2(visitor) VISA. I'm planning a trip to California from June 9 to June 17 with my friends. However, I got admitted into an US MBA program earlier this year and got my I-20 form already(start date August 12, 2016).
I understand that one person can only have one type of visa when entering US. I also know I definitely can not use F1 to enter US in June, because it's too early.
Thus, I'm wondering when should I schedule my F1 visa appointment and pay the fees?
Can I submit the appointment NOW, while making the appointment date somewhere after I come back from California (after June 17)?
If I apply now, will I get into trouble when I enter US in June with my B1/B2 visa?

Comment: Hi what did you finally do? I have the exact same situation.

Answer (score 2):

As per the [official site](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/wait-times.html) It only takes 3 calendar days to get an appointment at the Vancouver consulate and the processing time is 3 working days. You have almost two months. I would definitely not complicate my life having an F visa ongoing while visiting the US.

Problem is, the USCIS really doesn't like people who attempt to switch status from B1/B2 to F (because if it was your original intent to stay and learn in the US then you have committed fraud when you declared you are visiting) and while you claim you intend to leave before reentering on your F visa it's anyone's guess whether they believe it. If on the border they get wind of an F visa within the six months permitted by the entry on the visitor visa things can get very ugly, very fast. Don't do this. You don't need the trouble.

Remember the two important rules for border crossing: never lie to immigration and never offer information unasked. What's the purpose of the trip? California vacation. How long are you here? Just a week, here is my hotel/airbnb reservation/phone number of my host/whatever and my return plane ticket. Like that.